# findup-sync failing on Jenkins Server

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, grunt-cli

I'm building a jenkins job for an AngularJS app and it seems to have an issue everytime I try to run a Grunt task.

After executing

```
npm install && bower install && grunt
```

When the grunt tasks are running I'm getting this exception:

```
C:\.jenkins\workspace\my-app\node_modules\grunt\node_modules\findup-sync\lib\findup-sync.js:33
    }).flatten().uniq().value();
       ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.module.exports [as findup] (C:\.jenkins\workspace\my-app\node_modules\grunt\node_modules\findup-sync\lib\findup-sync.js:33:8)
    at Task.task.init (C:\.jenkins\workspace\my-app\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:427:16)
    at Object.grunt.tasks (C:\.jenkins\workspace\my-app\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt.js:120:8)
    at Object.module.exports [as cli] (C:\.jenkins\workspace\my-app\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\cli.js:38:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt:45:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

I googled it but I couldn't get any answers for it and I'm not sure if it's a bug with grunt itself or a missing dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using both npm and grunt like this:

```
call npm install

call grunt
```